# Sign changes of coefficients of a polynomial related to its roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

Let $a_1,a_2, \dots, a_n,b_1, \dots ,b_n$ be real numbers such that $a_i \ne 0$ and $b_1<b_2<\dots<b_n$.
Is the number of real roots of $P(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_k(x-b_k)^m$ (with $m\ge 1$ an integer) greater or less than the number of sign changes between $$a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,(-1)^ma_1$$ ?

I tried to solve it using recursion on $n$... but I'm completely stuck. I thought that considering the derivative of $P$ would be useful (or also the derivative of $\frac{P(x)}{(x-b_n)^m}$) but...

If $P$ has $k$ roots, then $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i(b_i-b_n)(x-b_n)^{m-1}$ has at least $k-1$ roots by Rolle's theorem if we consider the derivative of $\frac{P(x)}{(x-b_n)^m}$

The recursion works for almost every case but it can't conclude when $a_{n-1},(-1)^ma_1$and $a_n$ have the same sign...

Comment: It seems like [Descartes' Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) would be helpful here, but I haven't given it much thought.

Comment: Yeah I've seem that it was quite the same thing but can't figure out where it appears...

Comment: We could use Rolle's theorem in our induction if $P$ has $k$ real roots,$P'$ has at least $k-1$ real roots